# Using Java variable "Color" can you add a tint?

Tags: java, colors

I have a school assignment and part of it is when a cat collides with a dog the cat will scratch the dog and the dog will change colors.  Due to my teacher telling us to I used the Color variable (i.e. `dogs[i].setColor(Color.GRAY);`) I am wanting to add about 20 shades of red to the dog each time it's scratched.  For example, it starts at `(128, 128, 128)`, then after 1 scratch it will be `(148, 128, 128)`, after the `max (5)` it will be `(228, 128, 128)`.  I have seen somethings online that show how to do this but all the ones I have seen used different Color systems then the one my teacher told us to use.  Thank you for your time and I hope to hear back from you shortly!

Comment: Create a new Color per the assignment's rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change the color a bit, I would suggest to use the darket method:

```
dogs[i].setColor(dogs[i].getColor().darker());
```

Otherwise:

```
Color oldColor = dogs[i].getColor();
dogs[i].setColor(new Color(Math.max(0, oldColor.getRed()-10), oldColor.getGreen(), oldColor.getBlue());
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out, seems easy enough, never thought of editing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a variable in place of the r value that initially starts at 128? something like:

```
     int RedValue = 128;
```

and then upon collision, recolor the dog with the variable being in that place something like:

```
    RedValue += 20;
```

(First time Collision: RedValue = 148, then 168, until 228.)

```
    if(RedValue >= 228){ return; }

    Color c = new Color(RedValue, 128, 128)

    dogs[i].setColor(c);
```

I hope this helps, I program all my applications mostly using JavaFX, so I am sorry if this isn't what you are looking for, or isn't possible. However in JavaFX it is simple. I made a program that changes a circle's color on click, until the r value reaches 228. Then I realized this question didn't pertain to JavaFX. But maybe it could give you ideas,

**JAVAFX:**

Initialization:

```
private static int RedIncrements = 128;
```

Program:

```
        Shape c = new Circle(30,30,30);

        root.setCenter(c);

        c.setFill(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));

        c.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    if(RedIncrements==228){
                            return;
                    }
                    RedIncrements += 20;
                    c.setFill(Color.rgb(RedIncrements, 128, 128));
            }
        });
```

Link to full code: http://pastebin.com/guk0150p

Comment: Thanks!  I think I'm going to try the other answer first since it seems more like what should be occurring in a general instance.  But I love your way, it seems a lot like how I would have done it had I spent a couple more hours contemplating the issue haha.  So if I'm having issues with Victors than I'll definitely fall back in this!